# Flash AS2 Scale an MC from center position

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs4

I am using AS2 and I'm looking for a way to scale an MC from the center meaning that the width will expand equally on both sides.

For example .. If the movie clips needs to expand +10 then it would be +5 on the left and +5 on the right.

So, in order to simulate the movie clip going forward the position on the left would offset -5 then scale.

Hope this makes sense, if not just let me know.

Comment: Where's the center pivot located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is scaling, it's somewhat easy to do it:

```
var widthDiff : Number = newWidth - mc._width;
var heightDiff : Number = newHeight - mc._height;

var bounds:Object = mc.getBounds(this);
var moveXPerc : Number = (bounds.xMin / (bounds.xMin + bounds.xMax))-0.5;
var moveYPerc : Number = (bounds.yMin / (bounds.yMin + bounds.yMax))-0.5;
mc._width = newWidth;
mc._height = newHeight;
mc._x = mc._x + (moveXPerc * widthDiff);
mc._y = mc._y + (moveYPerc * heightDiff);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new movie clip on the setup window you will see registration point. You need to choose which one in the center.

[image]

if you want to change the registration point dynamically then check this [link](http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2003/09/dynamic-movieclip-registration-with-as2.html)

Additionally you shouol be careful about when you load a new object into MC then your new object 0,0 (topleft corner) will be equal to holder MC centre.